# Dúvida com CSS (Doubt about css)

Tags: css, css3

[image: Background]

Olá!

Como posso construir este plano de fundo em uma seção usando css? Sou um novato e comecei um projeto pessoal, mas não consigo construir esse background com CSS puro. É possível fazer isso? Pesquisei alguns sites, mas não resolveram minha dúvida.

Hello!

How can I build this background in a section using css? I'm a newbie and started a personal project, but I can't build this background with pure css. Was it possible to do it? I searched some sites, but they didn't solve my doubt.i used a div with `className={Style.background}` and applied a pseudo-element.:

```
.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #031f73;
  display: flex;
}

 .background::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 31.25rem;
  background: #fff;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 10% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

Comment: Cara tem muitas formas de fazer, posta o que vc já tentou e a gente pode te ajudar falando onde vc errou. Fazer para vc não resolveria o seu problema

Comment: Bom, inseri lá o que eu fiz @hugocsl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara não precisa de *pseudo-elemento*, corte diagonal não precisa de `clip-path`, para resolver as duas situações vc pode usar dois `linear-gradiente` na diagonal, um para fazer o azul e outro para fazer a linha.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.background {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 50%, #fff 50%, #fff calc(50% + 4px), transparent calc(50% + 4px), transparent),
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, navy 0%, navy 50%, transparent 50.1%);
  background-size: 110% 110%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: Realmente funcionou aqui...Agora essa linha branca, eu conseguiria posicionar ela em relação a uma distância (tipo um margin-left) em que eu quisesse? Mas desde já, obrigado hugo, ajudou bastante isso que você disse.

Comment: @YanDamasceno conseguiria sim, vc pode ajustas as % dentro do gradiente, ou se achar mais fácil ai sim usar um pseudo-elemento... Se vc achar que a resposta resolveu o problema lembre-se de marca-la como aceita nesse ícone **✓** abaixo das setinhas ao lada da resposta!